# Best practices for conditional rendering in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like some advice as to the best practice when conditionally rendering an element or component in react-native. My question is when the conditional is not true is it better to return null or just run the if condition? I understand that if you return null then the lifecycle methods are still run but my concern is if i do not return anything is there an impact or performance difference?

Example One

```
renderText(name) {
  if(name === 'Abba') {
    return <Text>{name}</Text>
  }
}
```

Example Two

```
renderText(name) {
  if(name === 'Abba') {
    return <Text>{name}</Text>
  } else {
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: For the topmost element it is a good practice to either return some JSX or `null`, i.e `return name === 'Abba' ?  <Text>{name}</Text> : null`. If it is inside of some JSX, you can use the `&&` operator instead, i.e `name === 'Abba' && <Text>{name}</Text>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think conditional rendering like this might be better.

```
renderText(name) {
  return (
    { name === 'Abby' &&
      <Text>
        {name}
      </Text>
    }
  )
}
```